# How to use PJSIP in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, sip, pjsip

I need help with two issues: 
1. I have downloaded and built the PJSIP library with the help of the link
http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone 
Now I could not find anymore tutorial/guide on how and which binaries to include in my XCode project. Also I could not find any sample code/guide that tells how to use the library, create SIP stack, start SIP session etc. etc. Please help me to include this library in my own project and build the SIP stack to connect to my SIP server. 
I am using XCode 5 with iOS SDK 7.1.1

2. Can I upload my iPhone application to App Store which uses PJSIP ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: 2. yes, you can submit. we have already submitted an application with PJSIP to AppStore, there was not any problem during the review proceure.

Comment: @holex; What I meant was that is there any licensing issue with the code ? Can we use the pjsip code in our app and call/distribute the app as our own app ? Also, please tell me the basic steps to create SIP stack using pjsip. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: yep, we are licensing it, because our app is not an open-sourced but commercial application. we used the sample iOS project from PJSIP's site, and their own documentation for developing our project. we had spent a several weeks learning the system and finally establishing the telephony service in an iOS app via our server.

Comment: @holex I will be very thankful if you could point me to the right direction in building the app. At-least share the web pages link where I can start building the application. Many thanks in advance

Comment: pjsip has dual licensing policy http://www.pjsip.org/licensing.htm so probably you should by it for commercial use

Comment: could you please send me how to do step by. I too did not get any steps to follow. Please guide me @AbbasAwan

Comment: Just use its included iOS sample as your starting point.

Comment: I want to implement video call using pjsip but unable to integrate the same. Audio call is working fine at my end. Could you please guide me how to implement video call in iOS version? Any clue would be highly appreciated. @AbbasAwan

Comment: @holex You mention that there is a sample iOS project from PJSIP's site. I'm probably being blind, but where? I poked around the GitHub and did a pgsip.org search for "iOS", and didn't see anything.

Comment: @Doug, I'm afraid that my comment was valid about 6 years ago :(

Answer (score 0):

PJSIP is under GPL License.If your app is commercial then you must buy license from PJSIP side.else your app is free distributable then there is no problem.